# Multisite installation but do plugins always have to be multisite compatible?

Tags: plugins, multisite

I have a multisite installtion and I have a question about using plugins in my multisite network.

If I plan to activate this plugin only in one of my subsites, is it necessary for this plugin to be multisite compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They shouldn't have to be multisite compatible.

Also remember that, there are two kinds of

- Passive compatibility: doing nothing multisite specific, just works without breaking anything.
- Active compatibility: changing or extending multisite specific
  behavior.

In case the plugin you want to use doesn't say anything about its compatibility on multisites, you just have to try them out, they may break things but they also can work without problem, it depends on what is their purpose.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! that was detailed and to the point :)

Comment: If you feel it helps, please accept my answer as correct :)

Comment: yep yep! I wanted to upvote/accept your answer since earlier but was unable to do so as this is the very first time I posted on stackexchange. so I had to wait a few minutes before I can accept your answer as correct :) thanks a lot!